# Limit [a-z0-9]* to 20 characters?

Tags: php, regex

I can get the `[a-z0-9]*` part from `[a-z0-9]*@example.com` with regex but I want to limit the `[a-z0-9]*` part with 20 characters. Is it possible with regex?

Edit: I have changed my mind, I'll not use `{0,20}`, insted I'll use `strlen()`. This one: `if (preg_match('/[a-z0-9]*@metu\.edu\.tr/',$_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) < 35)`

Comment: Keep in mind that dot (`.`) has a special meaning *everything* so you should escape it (`\.`). Also, this is not a valid expression for validating an email address.

Comment: Excellent introduction to regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[a-z0-9]{0,20}@example.com` will limit it to 0 to 20 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
[a-z0-9]{0,20}@example.com
```

or this:

```
[a-z0-9]{1,20}@example.com
```

Supposedly, there is a perfect regex for emails (assuming that's what you're trying to do) that was recently discovered:

```
/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i
```

Read more [here](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php).

Comment: That will require *exactly* 20 characters.

Comment: Thanks, just a small oversight.

Comment: As per comments by the author himself on the link you gave, this is not a perfect regex but a pragmatic approach based on what the author thought was important.